# How to install monodevelop on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I want to install monodevelop on ubuntu. Please anyone tell me how to install monodevelop on ubuntu step by step.

Comment: What about using Ubuntu depository?

Answer (score 16):

sudo apt-get install monodevelop

It should pop up with all the packages necessary to install it and then ask you: "Do you want to continue [Y/n]"

Just type y and hit enter.

Comment: +1 And to think, I spent several hours trying to do this. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Warning: The version of monodevelop in the repositories is outdated. The latest version is 6.x, but the repos only have 5.x.